# Java ProcessBuilder change drive

Tags: java, command-prompt, processbuilder

The following code:

```
Process p = new ProcessBuilder("G:").start();
```

gives me the following exception.

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "G:": CreateProcess error=5,
>   Access is denied.

What is wrong with it?

Comment: You can't "change drives" without some kind of `cmd` process context.  `G:` is simply not an executable command.  You can change the context of the execution location for a command by using [`directory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory(java.io.File)) property.  Essentially, what you're trying to do makes no sense, perhaps you could try and explain the problem you are trying to solve

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be looking for [`ProcessBuilder.directory(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#directory%28java.io.File%29) which *sets this process builder's working directory.* Something like,

```
String[] command = {""}; // <-- the command to run.
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
pb.directory(new File("G:\\"));
Process p = pb.start();
```

A bare `G:` sets a working directory outside the control of the JVM.

Comment: Note that you cannot change the current working directory of the running Java process itself. You can only set it for the child process in the ProcessBuilder.

Comment: @Thilo True, but you can call `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to *get* the current working directory.